# What are the URIs starting with file:// or application://?

Tags: url

Using Linux, I have more than once seen URIs of files and applications starting with `file://` and `application://`.

What are those URIs and how to use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme):

> The file URI scheme is a URI scheme specified in RFC 1630 and RFC
> 1738, typically used to retrieve files from within one's own computer.

and [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10):

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a
> particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes,
> does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the
> Internet.
>
> A file URL takes the form:
> `file://host/path`
>
> where host is the fully qualified domain name of the system on which
> the `path` is accessible, and `path` is a hierarchical directory path
> of the form `directory>/directory/.../name`.
>
> As a special case, `host` can be the string `localhost` or the empty
> string; this is interpreted as `the machine from which the URL is
> being interpreted'.

Most browsers support `file://` URI, co you can open file from your disk by using them in your browser address bar.

I don't think that `application://` URI is standarized - there is no info about it on Wikipedia and in RFC's on IETF site and in IANA site, so usage of this URI scheme is rather application specific and designed for application internal needs.

Comment: Indeed if I enter `file:///home/benjamin/my_file.txt`, I can access and open that file. So only web browsers can read the URI? Or can I use these URIs from the terminal too?

Comment: PS: I know the `application://` or `app://` from the use of zeitgeist, see: http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/dbus_api.html#event-serialization-format .

Comment: Standardization of `file://` URI was done in context of web browsing so all browsers should support it. Some other programs also should support it: there is support for `file://` in KDE apps, and I think that GNOME also have support for it. In `git` `file://` is one of ways to access repository. But as you can see it is application specific...

Answer (score 1):

Under GNU/Linux , its the "mimetypes" of "application" / "extension" , its ease to configure some about that , but for beginners can be complicated

for example , if you want to configure the "TeamSpeak 3 Server" protocol , just for the current user you can make the follow

```
1 - Install the teamspeak3 client in /opt/TeamSpeak3/Client


2 - Edit the file ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list


3 - Add under [Default Applications] , the follow line

    x-scheme-handler/ts3server=teamspeak.desktop

    and now save the file


4 - Create the "~/.local/share/applications/teamspeak3.desktop" file , just open a text editor , add the follow lines

    [Desktop Entry]
    Encoding=UTF-8
    Version=3
    Type=Application
    Terminal=false
    Name=TeamSpeak
    Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Client/ts3client_runscript.sh %u
    Path=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Client
    Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Icon/TeamSpeak3.png
    StartupNotify=false
    StartupWMClass=TeamSpeak
    X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false

5 - Update the mime database of the current user , with the command line

    $ update-mime-database $HOME/.local/share/mime

6 - Try to open a url with protocol for example , some like ->

    ts3server://8.9.36.132?port=9112
```

Now the web-browser , ask if you want to open with "TeamSpeak" , if you click "Open" the tool "TeamSpeak3 Client" must be connected to that server.

a brief explaniation

> > **The Mime Protocol , its the line**
> >
> > **x-scheme-handler/**
>
> in the same line the
>
> > **"ts3server="**
>
> its the web protocol
>
> > **"ts3server://"**
>
> in the same line the
>
> > **teamspeak.desktop**
>
> Determine the "Application" can open that protocol
>
> **The Desktop Entry**
>
> > **[Desktop Entry]**
> >
> > **Encoding=UTF-8**
> >
> > **Version=3**
> >
> > **Type=Application**
> >
> > **Terminal=false**
> >
> > **Name=TeamSpeak**
> >
> > **Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Client/ts3client_runscript.sh %u**
> >
> > **Path=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Client Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3/Icon/TeamSpeak3.png**
> >
> > **StartupNotify=false StartupWMClass=TeamSpeak X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false**

**Ok you see the above entry , the most important of that are**

> > **"Type" -> Should be application for this type of things**
> >
> > **"Terminal" -> Determine if a terminal are show or not**
> >
> > **"Name" -> The "Caption" / "Name" in the Menu of the desktop**
> >
> > **"Exec" -> Determine the script/binary path of app**
> >
> > **"Path" -> Determine the absolute path , with wine and dosbox cause troubles**
> >
> > **"Icon" -> Determine the Icon of the App**
> >
> > Note in the Exec Line at the end exist **%u** without double quote
> >     with that parameter the system can grab the 
> >     for stablish connection